# Как / где продавать своё программное обеспечение

Tags: работа

Сделал программу. Хочется её продавать.
Механизм лицензий на регистрационных ключах, которых ограниченное количество, и сгенерированы они все разными способами. Активация происходит через интернет.

Остаётся вопрос - как организовать продажу у себя на сайте, либо через сторонние сервисы.
Заниматься конителью с аттестатами WM мне как-то не хочется (хотелось бы, если бы жил гораздо ближе к их заведениям)

В общем - поделитесь опытом, господа. Или линки дайте, ибо гугл подобного пока мне не дал.

Comment: Продавать программы дело неблагодарное. Этим не заработаешь. Продавать надо решение проблем (индивидуально).

Comment: Обожаю русский менталитет. Ни слова по теме, только разубеждения -  всех оспорить и переучить. Но готов поспорить, вас пару раз плюсанут.  А если по теме вашего комментария - я и продаю решение проблемы, в виде алгоритма (программы). Про автоматизацию однотипных действий слышали?

Answer (score 3):

В капиталистическом мире, в котором к счастью или к несчастью мы живем, действует разделение труда.

В данном случае оно выражается в том, что те кто пишут программы не продают, а те кто продают программы ни разу их не пишут. И то и другое делать одновременно - не получается.

Найдите того, кто будет продавать вашу прогу и все. Обычно такими делишками занимаются всякие сайты контент-аггрегаторы. Их много, выставите свою прогу туда - обычно посредники берут от 10% до 50% от выручки (зависит от уровня жадности). Погуглите с ключевыми словами [shareware+download](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=shareware+download) - потусуйтесь на soft.cnews.ru, allsoft.ru - да мало ли их.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, можете попробовать на [allsoft.ru](http://allsoft.ru/) и подобных сайтах. Популярных не очень много в рунете.

**UPD**

Вот тут [www.plati.ru](http://www.plati.ru/asp/index.asp) получилось продать 1 скрипт, который просто так выложили, т.к. делали как решение одной проблемы заказчику и оформили как плагин.

Comment: туда же авторская программа [Softkey][1]

[1]:http://www.softkey.ru/author/